# Interpolate a data set for a defined time-step

Tags: interpolation

I have a set of data which looks like:

```
Time(s)     Data(arb.)  
0.000000000 937.800000
5.022000313 937.800000
10.04400015 937.800000
15.06500006 937.800000
20.08700037 937.800000
25.10900021 937.800000
...         ...
```

As you can see, data is recorded approximately every 5 seconds. I was wondering if there is a function with in Mathematica which will allow me to interpolate the whole data set and produce and interpolated data set at say every 1 second.

I have been experimenting with the `ListInterpolation` function but I am unsure on how to extend the examples given in the Documentation Centre to two column data and defining the time-step to something other than half way between two points.

Any help or push in the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: Look at `Interpolation.` Look at the first example under "Scope".

Comment: @bill s I tried the following: `Do[Print[Interpolation[Baratron20160404NightReducedData, i]], {i, 
  63395}]` but I'm unsure weather i is for the "time column" or the data column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some data in an array, then interpolated at a finer grid specified  by desiredPoints.

```
data = Thread[{Range[10], RandomInteger[{0, 5}, 10]}];
f = Interpolation[data];
desiredPoints = Range[2, 5, 0.1];
f[desiredPoints]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! So what is the "resolution" of this interpolation?  Could you explain your solution a little further? Thanks!

Comment: Look at the variable desiredPoints. This specifies the values at which you want to see the function, so it's in increments of 0.1 (as specified in the `Range` command).  But you can figure these things out yourself. Look up the help file for `Interpolation` and `Range`.

Comment: Okay so I think I understand your example. However when I load my data set into the interpolation function and set the range to `Range[0,63395,1]` and it errors!

Comment: Sorry I am a moron, I loaded a plot into the function not the data set. Apologies.